# Java Handler is abstract; Cannot be instatiated

Tags: java, handler

I am trying to set up a `Server` for a Worms-like game made in Java (to allow Multiplayer and in-game chat) but I have this specific problem.

I have tried changing the import, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Screenshot here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAlQK.png

```
package Server;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

import java.util.HashSet;

import java.util.logging.Handler;

public class Server {
    private static final int PORT = 9001;

    private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers =
            new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running.");
        try(ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            while (true) {
                new Thread(new Handler(listener.accept())).start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your IDE is right: Abstract classes cannot be instantiated!

Comment: Please post code in the question, not as an attached screenshot.

Comment: There is insufficient content to diagnose the problem, unless you provide an example of your problem, the question will be closed

Comment: It's Works For You:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873063/handler-is-abstract-cannot-be-instantiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, an abstract class cannot be instantiated, i.e., we cannot precede it with the word `new`, unless you also add the class body and implement any abstract methods. Alternately, you can create a class that extends Handler, and again make sure to add all of the abstract methods.

```
new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
```

Comment: Thak you , is my import correct ? 
import java.util.logging.Handler;

Comment: No .. you have to import   import android.os.Handler  not java.util.logging.Handler;